# Oozie server not starting with hadoop 0.23.0

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to run apache oozie version 3.2.0 incubating on hadoop 0.23.0 and when i execute bin/oozie-run.sh , the following error is displayed.

```
ERROR: Oozie could not be started

REASON: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ReflectionUtils

Stacktrace:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ReflectionUtils
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setServiceInternal(Services.java:349)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.<init>(Services.java:107)
    at org.apache.oozie.servlet.ServicesLoader.contextInitialized(ServicesLoader.java:38)
    ......

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    ... 27 more
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have not included the required hadoop libraries. Put the hadoop libs in libext folder and start oozie.